# Transposing data frame

Tags: r

This dataframe code :

```
f <- function (l) {
    l
}

data.frame(lapply(letters[1:2] , f))
```

which renders :

[image]

I'm attempting to transpose the rows to cols so `a,b` appear as :

```
X.a. a
X.b. b
```

I tried :

```
f <- function (l) {
    l
}

data.frame(t(lapply(letters[1:2] , f)))
```

But this renders :

[image]

Can I use transpose function `t()` to change how data frame appears ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this instead:

```
t(data.frame(lapply(letters[1:2] , f)))
```

Your code attempts to transpose the output of lapply, which is always a list.